# A read only modifier is required

Tags: typescript, tslint

In following class, `tslint` `readonly-keyword` is not allowing me to have a regular variable `timestamp` even though I'm reassigning the value within the class. I need to have the variable `timestamp` default to `false` and to be reassigned if needed.

```
export default class A {
    private timestamp: boolean = false;

    withTimestamp() {
        this.timestamp = true;
    }
}
```

If I do the following,

```
export default class A {
    private readonly timestamp: boolean = false;

    constructor() {
        this.timestamp = true;
    }
}
```

`tsserver` warning me

> `timestamp` is declared but it's value is never read.

How `this.timestamp` in constructor not accessing the same `timestamp` variable of the class?

Comment: `timestamp is declared but it's value is never read.` This is correct as the error says  you have never **read** the value, only assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like anything is wrong here...

```
private readonly timestamp: boolean = false;

constructor() {
    this.timestamp = true;
}
```

the double initialization probably shouldn't pass some lint flags, but doesn't seem like it's your issue.

Some stupid things you could try:

- Rename 'timestamp' to something else
- npm i
- Restart IDE